# What might be wrong if one defines \newcommand{\1}

Tags: macros

Coincidentally, I download a beamer theme from online source ([Feathertheme.sty](https://www.writelatex.com/templates/beamer-presentation-template-feather-theme/jcbpcdxqbxbf#.VH9rKvnNf3A)). When I try to add some packages to my own beamer file (say `\usepackage[xy]{xy}`), I see that it goes wrong, the background picture is corrupted.

After some trying, I find that the background picture is set by a command `\1` (defined in `beamerinnerthemeFeather.sty`). If I rename this command to a normal one (only letters), everything works.

So my question is why one can define `\1` as a command and what might go wrong in this case.

Comment: your question is totally unclear. tex commands can be a single non-letter like `\^` or `\1` or one or more letters like `\sin` whether the command `\1` causes problems is unrelated to its name, just its definition

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added some more information.

Comment: well as I say there is nothing special about `\1` if you have two packages (or a package and a beamer theme) that define commands of the same name then there will be some kind of clash either an error from `\newcommand` that the command is already defined, or if the packages just use `\def` then which is loaded second will "win" and over-write the first. The theme uses `\1` as the name of the background image so if you redefine `\1` that will break unless you change the macros to use some other name.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, I see. `xy-pic` already defined `\1`. Many thanks.